# how do I get the file revision list from a virtual file in an intellij project?

Tags: version-control, intellij-plugin

I am writing a plugin for intellij version "1.14.1" targetting intellij 2022.2.5

I would like to get a list of all commits involving a file or all commits for the project that can be searched for a file but when I search VcsUtil I don't find anything that gives me the revisions. I can get to a VcsHistoryProvider using

```
    val file = e.getData(CommonDataKeys.PSI_FILE)

    val project = e.project
    project?.let { p -> file?.virtualFile?.let { VcsUtil.getVcsFor(p, it)?.vcsHistoryProvider?. } }
```

but I can't figure out how to go from the vcsHistoryProvider to a list of revisions for a file. The searching I have done seems to be finding older versions where there was a VcsUtil.getRevisionsFor(file: VirtualFile) routine.

I tried:

```
    val maxTimeMs: Long = 90 * 24 * 60 * 60*1000 // 90 days
    val maxCount = 1000
    val settings = null
    val changes = location?.let { l ->
        project.let { p ->
            file?.virtualFile?.let {
                VcsUtil.getVcsFor(
                    p,
                    it
                )?.committedChangesProvider?.getCommittedChanges(settings, l, maxCount)
                    ?.filter { Date().time - it.commitDate.time <= maxTimeMs }
            }
        }
    }?.count()
```

but it gave me nothing at all.